# Appropriateness of a Question

Tags: support

I want to ask a question which is purely about hardware in my home network.

Is this the correct SE site to use?

I toyed with Server Fault, but in their Help section they say they consider anything "home" to be off topic.

If this SE site is not appropriate, can anyone suggest the correct site? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is welcome here

Comment: Thanks @OliverSalzburg....here goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its on how to use, deploy or set up hardware, its on topic. If its on what hardware to buy to solve a problem, its probably off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly it is, it may or not be on topic. Remember to always read the site's [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/help/asking) and [Help Centre - On topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) sections.